# What happens if a vampire bites an NPC?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, character-templates

I have an NPC who is a vampire.

When he bites another NPC or PC, is there the possibility, following the D&D 3.5 rules, that the victim will become a vampire or half-vampire? If someone heals the victim, will that prevent anything from happening? Where can I find the rules about vampire bites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **It depends on which attack kills and the HD of the victim**

Highlighting the key points here.

> Create Spawn (Su)
>
> **A humanoid or monstrous humanoid slain by a
>   vampire’s energy drain rises as a vampire spawn 1d4 days after burial.**
>
> **If the vampire instead drains the victim’s Constitution to 0 or lower,
>   the victim returns as a spawn if it had 4 or less HD and as a vampire
>   if it had 5 or more HD.** In either case, the new vampire or spawn is
>   under the command of the vampire that created it and remains enslaved
>   until its master’s destruction. At any given time a vampire may have
>   enslaved spawn totaling no more than twice its own Hit Dice; any spawn
>   it creates that would exceed this limit are created as free-willed
>   vampires or vampire spawn. A vampire that is enslaved may create and
>   enslave spawn of its own, so a master vampire can control a number of
>   lesser vampires in this fashion. A vampire may voluntarily free an
>   enslaved spawn in order to enslave a new spawn, but once freed, a
>   vampire or vampire spawn cannot be enslaved again.

The attacks in question are the Blood Drain

> Blood Drain (Ex)
>
> A vampire can suck blood from a living victim with
>   its fangs by making a successful grapple check. If it pins the foe, it
>   drains blood, dealing 1d4 points of Constitution drain each round the
>   pin is maintained. On each such successful attack, the vampire gains 5
>   temporary hit points.

And Energy Drain

> Energy Drain (Su)
>
> Living creatures hit by a vampire’s slam attack (or any other natural
>   weapon the vampire might possess) gain two negative levels. For each
>   negative level bestowed, the vampire gains 5 temporary hit points. A
>   vampire can use its energy drain ability once per round.

So in short, if you kill by biting, (Blood Drain) and the PC is level 5 or higher, then you get a vampire in 1d4 days in the ground. Otherwise you get a vampire spawn. But the key here is that the victim must DIE from the vampire's attacks AND be buried. Just being smacked around does not make you a vampire. If a PC dies the party can keep him from turning just by not putting him in the ground.

All quotes taken from the [Vampire](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/vampire.htm) entry on the SRD.

Comment: So, it turns in a Vampire only if die... I don't like this because I want to create a plot where a Vampire bite a victim and the PG must decide if they want to kill him because it will become a new vampire... there is a way to do this following the rules?

Comment: By RAW, not that I see. The Create Spawn ability is very clear. What you could do within RAW, is have rumors saying that a bite is enough. Make the players think that a bite will turn people. If they decide to kill, and find out later how it really works, you got some fun 'what did we do!?' potential there.

Comment: In that scenario (where you're stuck with a choice between killing a character, or letting the character become a monster), you might want to consider a Lycanthrope (werewolf, wererat, etc.) as a possible alternative.

Comment: Lycanthrope is interesting, maybe in the future but the quest with teh vampire is just started. About @Miatog, i'm not sure if I can do it because in the party there is a Paladin and a Cleric, and the know what a vampire bite can do or not, isn't it?

Comment: This is what Knowledge (Religion) rolls are for. If they haven't been putting ranks in it, you might get lucky and they won't know. If they have and you want to stick with RAW, you might want to follow @EthanKaminski 's advice.

Comment: @GiordiX There are a couple of different official monsters that can facilitate the *He's been [affected] by a [monster]! Do we kill him or risk him becoming a [monster]?* plot. I suggest asking a new question about that specifically.

Comment: @GiordiX Your vampires don't have to math the vampire as written in the monster manual.  If so, you should preemptively give players whose characters with appropriate knowledge skills checks to know the difference with an appropriate DC.  Those without said knowledge skills who rely on player knowledge may be surprised.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the rules for Vampires right in the Monster Manual or on the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/vampire.htm). The rules for how they create new vampires are shown under the *Create Spawn* ability:

> #### Create Spawn (Su)
>
> **A humanoid or monstrous humanoid slain by a vampire’s energy drain rises as a vampire spawn 1d4 days after burial.**
>
> **If the vampire instead drains the victim’s Constitution to 0 or lower, the victim returns as a spawn if it had 4 or less HD and as a vampire if it had 5 or more HD.** In either case, the new vampire or spawn is under the command of the vampire that created it and remains enslaved until its master’s destruction. At any given time a vampire may have enslaved spawn totaling no more than twice its own Hit Dice; any spawn it creates that would exceed this limit are created as free-willed vampires or vampire spawn. A vampire that is enslaved may create and enslave spawn of its own, so a master vampire can control a number of lesser vampires in this fashion. A vampire may voluntarily free an enslaved spawn in order to enslave a new spawn, but once freed, a vampire or vampire spawn cannot be enslaved again.

I've highlighted the key parts; biting and draining a victim of blood will create a Vampire if the NPC was powerful enough (most aren't) while either pummeling to death or draining the blood of a weak NPC will create a Vampire Spawn instead.

Either way, the target needs to be buried and then it takes a few days for them to rise.